# using an array member in a data structure

Tags: c

I have the following data structure:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int key;
    int *v;
}node;
```

... and the global variables:

```
node *multiway[10];
int contor=0;
```

I am trying to insert inside this structure all the nodes of a multiway tree, and all the kids of each node. In order to do this, I made this function:

```
int * getKids(int value,int n) //returneaza vectorul de copii ai unui nod
{
    //value-nodul parinte
    //n- numarul de noduri ale vectorului
    int *result=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    int counter=0;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==value)
        {
            counter++;
            result[counter]=i;
            printf("%d ",result[counter]);
        }
    }
    int copii[counter]; //in vector pun toti copiii valorii date, value
    for(i=1;i<=counter;i++)
    {
        copii[i]=result[i];
    }
    contor++;
    multiway[contor]=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //added this line after a comment
    multiway[contor]->key=value; //SEGMENTATION FAULT
    multiway[contor]->v=copii;
    return result;
}
```

My code compiles with no warnings, but when I run, it crashes. When I debug, I get a segmentation fault at the line which I commented with "Segmentation fault". Any idea of what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Arrays in C run from `0` to `length-1`, not from `1` to `length`.

Comment: `multiway` is an array of 10 pointers to `node`. Where did you allocate each element in the array? And what is the value of `counter`. Is it 10 or greater?

Comment: you never allocated any node objects into multiway

Comment: You can't dynamically allocate `copii` with: `int copii[counter];`. You should use `malloc`.

Comment: I added the following line before assigning an element of the multiway: multiway[contor]=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); I get a warning but at least my code doesn`t crash. Am I doing it ok?

Comment: @imp25 over and above `C99`, you can. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - I learn something new every day :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh `multiway[contor]->v=copii;` set local variable. So _You should use malloc._

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Right. Will add that, too. :-)

Comment: Allocate memory to multiway using malloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many issue with your code. To point out some of them

1. Array indexing

   ```
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       if(a[i]==value)
   ```

arrays in `c` has `0` based index. So, basically it should be `for(i=0;i< n;i++)`. You also did not show us what `a` is.

2. In case of

   ```
   int copii[counter];
   ```

what if `if(a[i]==value)` never becomes TRUE?

3. In case of

   ```
   multiway[contor]->key=value; //SEGMENTATION FAULT
   multiway[contor]->v=copii;
   ```

what if `contor` is more than `9`? You'll be overrunning the memory.

4. a function local variable's lifetime is till the function finishes execution. Once the function is finished, that variable won't be present anymore. Trying to access that variable produces [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

   ```
   multiway[contor]->v=copii;
   ```

in the above case, `copii` is local to `getKids()`, and after `getKids()` finishes execution, trying to access `multiway[contor]->v` will lead to UB.

Note: [Do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.